# How to remove border around legend and variable name in ggplot?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to remove the border around the legend in my barchart plot as well as the name variable. I only want the color and associated label.

[image]

below is the relevant code I'm using.

```
p = ggplot(df, aes(Type, value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") +  
  ...
theme(
  legend.position="top",
  legend.margin=margin(t = 0, unit='cm'), 
  legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA),
  axis.title.x=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
  axis.title.y=element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
  axis.text.y=element_blank(),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank() 
)
```

I've tried a few different things, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You can try to add theme(legend.key = element_blank())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of the legend name:

```
# dummy data
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),y=c(6,2,8,2,7,2),z=c("a","a","b","b","a","b"))

# use labs(fill="")
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
  labs(fill="")
```

The legend 'shadow' is a bit odd, what have you tried?

Comment: legend.key = element_blank() / element_rect(colour=NA) / element_rect(fill='transparent'), I think the border may have something to do with the other element_blank() theme options I have. I'm trying to remove most of the typical plotting elements so that this can look clean and minimal to fit with my dashboard. The legend name hiding works.

Comment: Oh wow, I just cycled through all the theme options experimenting with element_blank(), element_rect(fill='transparent') and element_rect(colour=NA) and it seems that using legend.box.background = element_rect(fill='transparent') forced the legend outline to appear. If I remove this option from theme, the border dissappears.